# How to create a custom slanted edge for button?

Tags: flutter

I have a button but the edges are slanted like this.

[image]

I tried using Container's `BoxDecoration` with `BorderRadius` to create a border according to the design but it's not very accurate.

```dart
final BorderRadius firstButtonBorder = BorderRadius.only(
  topRight: Radius.elliptical(3, 60),
  topLeft: Radius.elliptical(3, 60),
  bottomLeft: Radius.elliptical(3, 60),
  bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(3, 60),
);
```

[image]

How do I create the button so the edge is exactly like the first picture? Do I need to use custom painter or something? Also the button need to be able to specify custom width as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a clippath widget as child. Nested in it the container.

```
child:ClipPath(
  child:Container(),
  clipper: CustomClips()
)
class CustomClips extends CustomClipper<Path>{
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width / 12, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    return path;
  }
  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: @Zerocchi If this or variations to path.lineTo() works for you, accept it as answer.

Comment: I will try your approach once I'm back to my workplace. Thanks!